# Mvn test Exception in provider error when running tests but all tests pass individually

Tags: java, maven, testng

I'm using maven surefire 2.22.0 with testNG 7.1.0 and all my unit tests pass on their own even when run in sequence however when running mvn test I get this error, I haven't seen much on this error but I'm guessing theres some issue with Maven trying to find or initiate testNG to start running the tests??

not sure why they all pass manually though... I'm not passing any special flags in my manual config, hoping someone has some ideas here?

I've edited this to show the full stack trace with mvn test -X

```
Exception in provider
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1287)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1144)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:910)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:910)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ebay.kernel.exception.BaseException.printStackTrace(BaseException.java:139)
        at org.testng.internal.Utils.buildStackTrace(Utils.java:320)
        at org.testng.internal.Utils.longStackTrace(Utils.java:303)
        at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateTable(TestHTMLReporter.java:169)
        at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateLog(TestHTMLReporter.java:359)
        at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.onFinish(TestHTMLReporter.java:38)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:895)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:859)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:590)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:93)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:155)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:92)
        ... 30 more

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException (SurefireHelper.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1160)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess (InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ebay.kernel.exception.BaseException.printStackTrace (BaseException.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.buildStackTrace (Utils.java:320)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.longStackTrace (Utils.java:303)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateTable (TestHTMLReporter.java:169)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateLog (TestHTMLReporter.java:359)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.onFinish (TestHTMLReporter.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent (TestRunner.java:895)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun (TestRunner.java:859)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run (TestRunner.java:590)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest (SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially (SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun (SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run (SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite (SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run (SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially (TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally (TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites (TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run (TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run (TestNGExecutor.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute (TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke (TestNGProvider.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2 (ReflectionUtils.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke (ProviderFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider (ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess (InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
```

this is my configuration in my project POM, these are just the relevant sections because the POM is quite large.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
              <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
              <version>2.22.0</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: First use an up-to-date version of maven-surefire-plugin (version 3.1.2; https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html) and remove the manualy added dependency to surefire plugin. Are you using only TestNG as testing framework?

Comment: The latest released version of TestNG is `7.8.0` (JDK11) and `7.5.1`(JDK8). Please upgrade to it and retry. If the problem persists, then please edit your question and share a sample test code that can be used to reproduce the problem.  The stack-trace seems to indicate that this bug perhaps has been fixed in newer versions